# Proof using natural deduction of $\small\forall x~[A(x)\to\exists y~[B(y)\land C(y,x)]] \vdash\forall x~[\exists y~[A(x)\to(B(y)\land C(y,x))]]$

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to construct a formal proof of the argument:
$$\forall x~\Big[A(x)\to\exists y~\big[B(y)\land C(y,x)\big]\Big] ~\vdash~\forall x~\Big[\exists y~\big[A(x)\to(B(y)\land C(y,x))\big]\Big]$$
using natural deduction, but I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: What are your rules of inference and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Don't make us reinvent the heel.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031314/pa-rightarrow-exists-y-qy-vdash-exists-y-pa-rightarrow-qy-using-natural-d?rq=1 (listed under the "Related" questions on the right) seems very relevant to solving this problem.